# How to make instance of global obj that can be mutated and available through all modules for every specify (node env, express fr) route post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module, routes

As a newbie I started to "develop" some app. The idea is that user fill the form and then I mutate it (form) data with help of the other site and finally cast it back to the user with help of socket.io

The process can take few seconds so I try to pass back the data partially with socket.io - so user can start browse the data, when the rest is still calculated or in transit. I even add some graph for that - so user is informed when ALL data has been throw at him, so he can browse results without any further changes/updates.

**TL:DR** - Then concept is working fine, **but as a newb I have problem with proper maintaining my code and cut it to pieces cause now work with this 5k lines is a total *nightmare*.**

The users that would want to modify the code for sure will have problem with encompass it so they could not use it easily.

*The code from form is received in route like this:*

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');
var body_parser = require('body-parser');

var module1 = require('./module1.js');

router.post('/page', function(req, res) {

  // globalS object
  var globals = {
    a : 'a',
    b : 'b',
    c : 'c', // and so on...
    mutatedData1 = '',
    mutatedData2 = ''
  };

  // form data (from the form that action is set to "/page" and method is "post")
  var fomrData = req.body.form_input_name;

  // request to get first part of the data
  var dataMutation = request('https://www.facebook.com', function(err, resp, body) {
    if (resp.statusCode === 200) {
      globals.mutatedData1 = body.substr(0, 100);

      // page render (I'm using ejs template)
      res.render('page');

      // another request to get second part of the data
      var otherPageRequest = request('https://www.google.com', function(error, response, content) {
        globals.mutatedData2 = content.substr(0, 100);
      });


      // lets suppose thet here are more request, more calculation, more emits, recursion, loops, callbacks etc.
      // and this is going for 5 thousands lines of code...

      // so for example the next request I would like to make, could be placed in a module1, then the code could look cleaner and more friendly to the user that want to use it/modify it
    }
  });


});

module.exports = router;
```

So I could have been given an example how I can cut my code in to the modules cause right now I have a headache when not even look at the code or touch it.

I have tried build globals module that is required in the rest of the modules, but every user that request is just adding the data to the globals object (which contains the old data!), and do not create a new instance of it - only for this specific request. So data is growing in numbers and not giving proper results.

**TL:DR - Every time user fill the form I need to have new globals object that is available through all modules so they can update the data in it.** *The old globals object data must not pollute - when I open another browser on my localhost, and fill the form, the app will work with this new data only and do not present the old data with the new data mixed together.*

Any idea how to resolve that? Thanks for any help/guidance/links.

Answer (score 1):

I may be understanding incorrectly but it seems like you could use some form of "id" (Perhaps the socket.io id). Basically rather than global = {data} have global[id] = {data}, then each of your modules get passed this id that they can use to reference the correct data. You could at the top of each of your modules have something like `var globalData = global[id];` Then all you have to do is rename each instance of "global" to "globalData".

If i misunderstood something let me know!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your input-I do use socket.id-I create a room for every socket connection(user)and when I emit data I emit it then to specific rooms(users). Some other features works like that too-like chat.So in other words you propose to connect the globals object with an socket.id-but honestly I thinks it could be troublesome. How to move globals object from router.post to put it in global space with an socket.id that I get -inside- router.post?You cant have prepare socked.id on start page and pass it with post request -socket connection will be break (but I can be wrong in that manner).

Comment: Well than rather than using a socket id you could make your own id value, then if needed the client could store it as local storage or as a cookie